# SQL Execution Time Slowing Down, Code First

Tags: c#, code-first, dbcontext

I've got a bit of a strange one here. I'm using Entity Framework Code First in a console app that runs a batch process. The code loops round a series of dates executing a stored procedure every time.

Currently it loops about 300 times and over time, each execution gets slower and slower till near the end when its crawling.

I've tried memory profiling and that's not it. Here's example code.

```
 _dbContext = new FooContext();
 _barService = new BarService(new GenericRepository<Bar>(), _dbContext);

 for (var date = lastCalculatedDate.AddDays(1); date <= yesterday; date = date.AddDays(1))
 {
     _barService.CalculateWeightings(date);
 }
```

And all CalculateWeightings does is (I'm using nlog as well)

```
public void CalculateWeightings(DateTime dateTime)
{
    _logger.Info("Calculating weightings for {1}", dateTime);
    Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC CalculateWeightings @dateTime", new SqlParameter("@dateTime", dateTime);
}
```

The stored procedure just populates a table with some records. Nothing complicated, the table ends up with a couple of 1000 rows in it so the problem isn't there

Any thoughts?

For those of you wanting to see the sql. Its a bit of a behemoth but I can't see any reason this would slow down over time. The number of rows dealt with are pretty low.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateWeightings]
    @StartDate DateTime,
    @EndDate DateTime,
    @TradedMonthStart DateTime,
    @InstrumentGroupId int
AS
BEGIN
    ---- GET ALL THE END OF DAY PRICINGS FOR MONTHLYS ----
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                    (
                        PARTITION BY RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemName, 
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR, RawTrades.LastUpdate, 103) 
                        ORDER BY RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemName, RawTrades.LastUpdate DESC
                    ) AS [Row], 
    RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemID AS MonthId, 
    Sequences.ActualStartMonth,
    Sequences.ActualEndMonth,
    RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemName AS [MonthName], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, RawTrades.LastUpdate, 103) AS LastUpdate,
    RawTrades.Price
    INTO #monthly
    FROM RawTrades
    INNER JOIN Sequences ON RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemId = Sequences.SequenceItemId AND RawTrades.FirstSequenceId = Sequences.SequenceId
    WHERE RawTrades.FirstSequenceID IN (SELECT MonthlySequenceId FROM Instruments WHERE InstrumentGroupId = @InstrumentGroupId) 
    AND [Action] <> 'Remove'
    AND LastUpdate >= @StartDate
    AND LastUpdate < @EndDate
    AND ActualStartMonth >= @TradedMonthStart
    ORDER BY RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemID, RawTrades.LastUpdate DESC

    ---- GET ALL THE END OF DAY PRICINGS FOR QUARTERLYS ----
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                    (
                        PARTITION BY RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemName,  
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR, RawTrades.LastUpdate, 103) 
                        ORDER BY RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemName, RawTrades.LastUpdate DESC
                    ) AS [Row], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, RawTrades.LastUpdate, 103) AS LastUpdate, 
    Sequences.ActualStartMonth,
    Sequences.ActualEndMonth,
    RawTrades.Price
    INTO #quarterly
    FROM RawTrades
    INNER JOIN Sequences ON RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemId = Sequences.SequenceItemId AND RawTrades.FirstSequenceId = Sequences.SequenceId
    WHERE RawTrades.FirstSequenceID IN (SELECT QuarterlySequenceId FROM Instruments WHERE InstrumentGroupId = @InstrumentGroupId)  
    AND Action <> 'Remove' 
    AND LastUpdate >= @StartDate
    AND LastUpdate < @EndDate
    AND RawTrades.Price > 20
    ORDER BY RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemID, RawTrades.LastUpdate DESC

    ---- GET ALL THE END OF DAY PRICINGS FOR QUARTERLYS ----
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                    (
                        PARTITION BY RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemName,  
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR, RawTrades.LastUpdate, 103) 
                        ORDER BY RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemName, RawTrades.LastUpdate DESC
                    ) AS [Row], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, RawTrades.LastUpdate, 103) AS LastUpdate, 
    Sequences.ActualStartMonth,
    Sequences.ActualEndMonth,
    RawTrades.Price
    INTO #seasonal
    FROM RawTrades
    INNER JOIN Sequences ON RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemId = Sequences.SequenceItemId AND RawTrades.FirstSequenceId = Sequences.SequenceId
    WHERE RawTrades.FirstSequenceID IN (SELECT SeasonalSequenceId FROM Instruments WHERE InstrumentGroupId = @InstrumentGroupId) 
    AND Action <> 'Remove' 
    AND LastUpdate >= @StartDate
    AND LastUpdate < @EndDate
    AND RawTrades.Price > 20
    ORDER BY RawTrades.FirstSequenceItemID, RawTrades.LastUpdate DESC

    ---- BEFORE WE INSERT RECORDS MAKE SURE WE DON'T ADD DUPLICATES ----
    DELETE FROM LiveCurveWeightings
    WHERE InstrumentGroupId = @InstrumentGroupId
    AND CalculationDate = @EndDate

    ---- CALCULATE AND INSERT THE WEIGHTINGS ----
    INSERT INTO LiveCurveWeightings (InstrumentGroupId, CalculationDate, TradedMonth, QuarterlyWeighting, SeasonalWeighting)
    SELECT
    @InstrumentGroupId,
    @EndDate,
    #monthly.ActualStartMonth,
    AVG(COALESCE(#monthly.Price / #quarterly.Price,1)) AS QuarterlyWeighting,
    AVG(COALESCE(#monthly.Price / #seasonal.Price,1)) AS SeasonalWeighting
    FROM #monthly
    LEFT JOIN #quarterly 
        ON #monthly.ActualStartMonth >= #quarterly.ActualStartMonth 
        AND #monthly.ActualEndMonth <= #quarterly.ActualEndMonth 
        AND #quarterly.[Row] = 1
        AND #monthly.LastUpdate = #quarterly.LastUpdate
    LEFT JOIN #seasonal 
        ON #monthly.ActualStartMonth >= #seasonal.ActualStartMonth
        AND #monthly.ActualEndMonth <= #seasonal.ActualEndMonth 
        AND #seasonal.[Row] = 1
        AND #monthly.LastUpdate = #seasonal.LastUpdate
    WHERE #monthly.[Row] = 1
    GROUP BY #monthly.ActualStartMonth

    DROP TABLE #monthly
    DROP TABLE #quarterly
    DROP TABLE #seasonal

END
```

Comment: Share the code of CalculateWeightings  sp

Comment: A table that gradually grows larger is exactly the kind of thing that will generate the kind of behavior you observe.  It may help to provide the code of `CalculateWeightings` in case the SO community can help spot inefficiencies there.

Comment: @Romil I'll get back to you on that, its not very complicated so I'd be suprised if that was the problem

Comment: @mellamokb Even a table that only grows to 2000 rows?

Comment: It depends of course on what you are doing.  For example, a subquery partial sum across all previous rows to generate a running total will get slow very quickly for a small number of rows.  Or if you are inner joining a table with itself multiple times to create some sort of hierarchy or graph mapping.

Comment: If you procedure is an O(n^2) operation, then yes you will see a dramatic slowdown with just a few thousand rows.  Classic example is a loop (cursor) within a loop (cursor)

Comment: No cursors present (thank god), I'll get you the SP

Comment: Have you looked at Sql Profiler to see if what is being sent to the db is what you think/expect it is?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue may be due to your EF tracking graph getting too large. If you re-use your context in a batch operation with the tracking graph on every time you perform an operation it needs to enumerate the graph. With a few hundread items this isnt an issue but when you get into the 000s it can become a massive problem. Take a look at my article on this [here](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/05/entityframework-performance-and.html) and see if you think it matches the issue.

If you take a look at the graph below for insert operations you can see around 1000 inserts (when tracking is on) starts to sharply spike in execution time. (also note the log scales on the axis)

[image]